# Android Architecture Patterns

Tags: android, architecture, broadcastreceiver

Which architecture pattern do you use for Android development? Until now I have been using the `MVC` pattern with `BroadcastReceivers` to communicate between layers but there must be something better than this. The Broadcast is killing me with all its registers and unregisters. So any answer will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There isn't a single architecture pattern that is suitable for every Android application.  If you want specific suggestions you need to be more specific about what problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

First, architecture is something that should be related to the system/application you are developing **not** the programming platform you are using. Yes some languages enforce specific practice and patterns, but this does not mean that for specific application another architecture will be more appropriate.

There is no such *universal architecture* for all android applications.

`MVC` and `broadcast` (or generally *event-driven communication*) have completely different objectives.

In brief, `MVC` is to separate the data from the presentation, while `broadcast` is to facilitated communication between unknown parties (i.e. a `broadcast` receiver can respond to the specific event regardless which component sends it)

Answer (score 0):

That's a bad question.  The answer is always "Whatever fits the program you're trying to write".  Patterns aren't meant to be plugged in as solutions to a problem, patterns are a language to describe your architecture.

But given the rest of your question, I think you're doing something really weird.  A very basic Android app is generally MVC-  the Activity is the Controller, the View classes are the View, and the Model is created by you (or may not be bothered with for a simple app).  BroadcastReceivers are generally rarely used, they're meant to be notified of asynchronous events from the OS or other applications.  They aren't meant for intra-app communication.  Also, there are no "layers" in Android.  What exactly are you doing?

Comment: Yes, I know that the use of BroadcastReceivers is weird. But I haven't found any other solution to communicate between layers (E.g. if I want to get some records from DB with a Thread the Broadcast is helping me to communicate with the Activity. The flow is Activity makes a request to Controller and Controller to Database and after the records are retrieved successfully the Database sends a Broadcast to Controller and Controller to Activity to display the result on the screen).

Comment: I know this is weird and this is why I posted this question to find a better way to develop Android apps.

Comment: Let me guess-  you're an enterprise Java programmer?  That seems to be a very over-engineered solution, the type that code tends to resemble.  You're overthinking it.  Make a thread do the database query.  When its done, send a message to the Activity by posting it to a message queue.  Broadcast receivers are used when you need to send a message to an unknown number of interested receivers, not for when you want to tell a specific component that an event occured.

Answer (score 0):

While it is true, at some level, that there can't be a single architecture for Android apps, I would say that there, most definitely, are architectural good ideas.  MVC is a really good idea in Android.  You shouldn't have to use BroadcastReceivers to support it: you can probably do a lot with ContentObservers.  Also, have a look at Virgil Dobjanschi's talk on RESTful Android is brilliant.  Check it out: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE